# ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from partially initialized module 'database.db'

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-import, fastapi, pydantic

my name is Leo and recently I've taken a long break (around 2 years) from programming and while lots of things have not changed, I seem to have forgotten some more basic aspects such as how to fix the error I have around imports.

[I have a FastAPI, sqlalchemy and pydantic project on github](https://github.com/Daftscientist/project-1) this project has quite a few files and i seem to have confused myself. Another set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

This error is an `ImportError` and is stating that `cannot import name 'Base' from partially initialized module 'database.db'`

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Base' from partially initialized module 'database.db' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

If someone could take a look at my code, on my GitHub, it would be greatly appreciated.
To reproduce the error just follow the steps to start my code on my [readme](https://github.com/Daftscientist/project-1#installation)

The code:
db.py file:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker
from database.models import allocation, server, user

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db"

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True, echo=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)
Base = declarative_base(name="base")

async def init(dev=False):
    """ Initializes the database. """
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        if dev:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

main.py file:

```py
import sanic
import routes
import asyncio
from core import cache
from database import db
from errors import custom_handler

app = sanic.Sanic("backend")
app.config.FALLBACK_ERROR_FORMAT = "auto"
prefix = routes.routes_v1[0]

asyncio.run(cache.init())
asyncio.run(db.init(True))

app.error_handler = custom_handler.CustomErrorHandler()

for route in routes.routes_v1[1]:
    app.add_route(
        handler=route[1],
        uri=f"/{prefix}{route[0]}",
    )
```

database.models.allocation.py file:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Uuid, DateTime
import uuid
from database.db import Base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Allocation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Allocation'

    identifier = Column(Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    uuid = Column(Uuid, nullable=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    server_uuid = Column(Uuid, nullable=True, default=None)
    ip = Column(String, nullable=False)
    port = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    node_identifier = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
```

I have tried removing imports that have to do with Base and database.db route.

I know it might be seen as a simple error but I've fully managed to confuse myself.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please include the relevant code that reproduces the problem in your question: an external repository can disappear at any time and won't be useful for future readers. In this case it's a circular import - you're importing your models (`database/models/...`) in `database/db.py`, and the models are trying to import `Base` from `database/db.py`, but this module is where you're trying to import from, so the code that defines `Base` hasn't run yet. Move the model import to the end of the file after `Base` has been defined.

Comment: Sorry, il make sure to post code blocks with the relevant code in the future.

Comment: I've fixed the error as in my db.py file `from database.models import allocation, server, user` imported and by removing it (it wasn't used) it runs (with other errors).